# How to clean Pool main drain

Tags: water, drain, pool

New to this;

I have used vinegar overnight, baking soda, a pumice stone, still it will not budge.

I tried muriatic acid via watering can direct on it, 1:10 parts water, still nothing, then 5:10 parts still nothing.

Has anyone had the same issue with a quick solution ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the water in your pool had a high level of metals in it (copper, iron, manganese, etc.). These metals are suspended in the water, even though the water appears to be clear. Citric Acid is probably your best chance of removing metal staining. Here is a decent product to remove the staining you already have...

[image: Sea Klear Metal Remover]

You should also look into maintaining the metals in your pool water with a chelator such as this...

[image: Bio Guard Metal Stain Preventer]